# Selecting next date from a list of services

Tags: sql

Let's assume I have the following table which is created by using the below query.

**NEXT() command is not available**

```
ID  ClientID    Service_Code    Date of Service
101 100030      1               2011-04-06
102 100030      6               2011-04-06
103 100030      9               2011-05-26
104 100030      11              2011-09-29
105 100030      6               2011-09-29
```

and I would like to add a column that will show the next  service date
For example

```
ID  ClientID    Service_Code    Date of Service Next Service Date
101 100030      1               2011-04-06      2011-04-06
102 100030      6               2011-04-06      2011-05-26
103 100030      9               2011-05-26      2011-09-29
104 100030      11              2011-09-29      2011-10-29
105 100030      6               2011-10-29      NULL
```

I have used the query below but is returning the following

```
ID  ClientID    Service_Code    Date of Service Next Service Date
101 100030      1               2011-04-06      2011-05-26
102 100030      6               2011-04-06      2011-05-26
103 100030      9               2011-05-26      2011-05-26
104 100030      11              2011-09-29      2011-05-26
105 100030      6               2011-10-29      2011-05-26
```

Any suggestions???

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add the query to your question (click edit to change your post) - it appears to be missing.

Comment: So where is your query string?

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please edit your question and include the queries referenced in the question and add the tag appropriate for the database you are using.

Comment: I would like to answer this question but I can't -- first of all, all the dates are in the past -- which seems strange when talking about a query that is going to project to the future.  2nd there are no rules that I can think of that define how to derive the next service date from the information given.  Finally the OP said there was a query posted but none exists.

Comment: LOL, I forgot to include the query, sorry about that. Well I kind of figured it out. Answer is below. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Yoismel All I did was add an ORDER BY and LIMIT clause to your answer.  Your answer does not guarantee that the date returned is the most immediate next date.  If the same person had 3 entries: one for day x, day x+1 and day x+30, your answer could return day x+30 instead of day x+1 since you don't include an ORDER BY statement.  Also, you need to LIMIT subqueries like this to only return one column from one row or else you'll throw an error if a patient has more than 2 entries in the billing_tx_history table.  You may also want to handle cases where a patient has only two entries from the same date, if that's a possibility.

```
SELECT 
    btx.PATID, 
    btx.v_patient_name, 
    service_code,
    ID, 
    date_of_service,
    (
        SELECT date_of_service
        FROM billing_tx_history btx1
        WHERE btx1.PATID = btx.PATID AND date_of_service > btx.date_of_service
        ORDER BY date_of_service
        LIMIT 1
    ) as next_date_of_service
FROM 
    billing_tx_history btx 
INNER JOIN 
    episode_history ep 
ON 
    btx.FACILITY = ep.FACILITY 
    AND btx.PATID = ep.PATID 
    AND ep.episode_number= btx.episode_number 
WHERE 
    (ep.date_of_discharge IS NULL OR ep.date_of_discharge > getDate()) 
    AND service_code NOT LIKE 'DELETE' 
    AND btx.patid = '1000030'
```

Comment: Sorry, I was kind of new in stackoverflow when I posted this question and never followed up. I did not think about that since the records are ordered by date of service and I didn't have to face that problem, but you are right. I will include the order by to he query. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Without more details, this is the best answer I can give.  This works in PostgreSQL 9.4.  I'm making a lot of assumptions as to what you want, so feel free to edit your question with more details if this doesn't do it.

```
CREATE TABLE t 
(
  id integer, 
  clientid integer, 
  service_code integer, 
  date_of_service date
);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (101, 100030, 1, '2011-04-06');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (102, 100030, 6, '2011-04-06');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (103, 100030, 9, '2011-05-26');

SELECT
  *,
  (
    SELECT date_of_service 
    FROM t AS b 
    WHERE b.id > a.id 
    ORDER BY id 
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS next_service_date
FROM t AS a
ORDER BY id;
```

Which gives the following result:

```
 id     clientid     service_code     date_of_service     next_service_date
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 101     10030             1            2011-04-06          2011-04-06
 102     10030             6            2011-04-06          2011-05-26
 103     10030             9            2011-05-26            <NULL>
```

Answer (score 0):

the code below did it

```
SELECT btx.PATID, btx.v_patient_name, service_code,ID,
    date_of_service,
   (
    select  date_of_service
    from billing_tx_history btx1
    where btx1.PATID = btx.PATID and date_of_service > btx.date_of_service
   ) as next_date_of_service
```

FROM billing_tx_history btx INNER JOIN episode_history ep
ON btx.FACILITY = ep.FACILITY AND btx.PATID = ep.PATID and ep.episode_number= btx.episode_number
WHERE (ep.date_of_discharge IS NULL OR ep.date_of_discharge > getDate()) AND service_code NOT LIKE 'DELETE'
        and btx.patid = '1000030'